# Laravel Telescope - Requests is empty and keeps firing XHR request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I use Laravel telescope on Laravel fresh install and I am using docker for development I have image: `webdevops/php-apache-dev:7.2` and `mysql`, when I tried to access Laravel telescope no request is shown.

## I tried this:

1.) Installed fresh Laravel 5.8 and run `factory('App\User',10)->create()` in tinker for seeding data

2.) `composer require laravel/telescope`, run `php artisan telescope:install`,`php artisan migrate`,`php artisan telescope:publish`

3.) Go to terminal project directory, run `sudo docker ps`

4.) Get the container id of apache container

5.) Run `sudo docker inspect {docker container id}`

6.) Get the ip_address of the container

7.) Run `sudo docker exec -it {docker container id}`

8.) cd into `var/www/htdocs`(this is where my laravel project lives inside docker container)

9.) Run `php artisan serve --host={ip_address of apache container}`

10.) Go to browser hit url `http://{ip_address of apache container}:{port in artisan serve}`

11.) Login user and refresh page

12.) Open another tab for Laravel telescope `http://{ip_address of apache container}:{port in artisan serve}/telescope`

13.) No request shown, and if I check into console no error detected and in network XHR request keeps firing even i am not reloading the page with this Request URL: `http://172.21.0.3:8002/telescope/telescope-api/requests?tag=&take=1&family_hash=`

## But still request is empty

I expect to see a request/s when I visit url `http://{container_id}:{php artisan serve port}/telescope` but request is empty in the page.

## network Tab in Browser Image

[image]

## Terminal inside Docker apache image

[image]

## docker-compose.yml image

[image]